# Android Hello World My First App has got big size

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created my first Android Hello World App from this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html. I did everything exactly as described in the lesson. Then I run this App on my tablet. I was wondering how much space my program takes on permanent storage. OMG! It takes 5.8 Mb! 5.8 Mb for only phrase "Hello world".

How to decrease the size? I think 0.5 Mb is enough for Hello World Application...

Comment: Check if the project is using some libraries! Consult the build.gradle file and look out for the dependencies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409139/why-does-my-app-size-on-device-differ-than-the-apk-or-play-store-size

Heree you can find an explanation.

Comment: for starters, try exploding the apk and see what all it contains. Then you can think about optimizing it.

Comment: have you considered all the framework behing your phrase? the UI, icons, etc? also, this has been asked previously, for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669134/reduce-android-application-size?rq=1

Comment: I thought you understand that Hello World App is EMPTY application. But You did not!

Answer (score 4):

Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269850/how-to-reduce-android-apk-size).

Use Android ProGuard tool. The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer.